# Proper way to escape a semicolon in AWS Aurora Query Editor?

Tags: amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I am currently trying to insert some data into an AWS Aurora serverless instance through the query editor and I am finding my INSERT query crashes since it contains a semicolon.
An usual approach in MySQL dbs is to change the delimiter, however this is not working either:

DELIMITER customeol
UPDATE mytable SET ';

DELIMITER ;

Is there any way to actually insert semicolons through the query editor? or there is no other option than to actually create an outside function to store data into it (e.g through a lambda)